# Does anyone know some theorem to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Recently I have been studying calculus and I got stuck with this problem:

I already know that the functions $f$ and $g$ are both real functions, defined and continuous in $[a,b]$, such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=2\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt.
\end{equation}

I need to show that exists $c\in[a,b]$, such that $f(c)=2g(c)$.

To solve that, I've started doing:
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)=2[G(b)-G(a)]=2\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt,
\end{equation}
considering $F(t)$ and $G(t)$ antiderivatives for $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. Multiplying all terms by $\frac{1}{(b-a)}$, we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=2\frac{[G(b)-G(a)]}{b-a}.
\end{equation}
I don't know the theorem, but I surely know that exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that
\begin{equation}
F'(c)=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}\Leftrightarrow f(c)=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=2\frac{[G(b)-G(a)]}{b-a},
\end{equation}
whitch gives me
\begin{equation}
f(c)=2\frac{[G(b)-G(a)]}{b-a}.
\end{equation}

I'm almost there, but I feel that I'm missing something. Please, help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=2\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt \iff \int_{a}^{b}(f(t)-2g(t))dt=0.
$$

The mean value theorem of integral calculus states that there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b h(t)dt= h(c)(b-a).$$

Taking $h(t)=f(t)-2g(t)$ we are done.